# how to insert both icon as well as back button on action bar (like in whatsapp)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am making a Chat Application and so wanted to add both icon as well as back button on my `actionbar()` in chat activity (like it is in WhatsApp) but I'm not able to set both things...

**here is the code:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
    initControls();
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String itemname = intent.getStringExtra("itemname");

    actionBar.setTitle(itemname);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

}
```

The problem is that both the things are not getting set at the same time with the above code only back button shows up and if I remove code for back button then icon shows up... How to set both things???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the default action bar, make your custom toolbar and add an imageview in it.
Something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
>
     <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageToolBar"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarText"
            style="@style/TextToolBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageToolBar"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageToolBar"
            android:text="Your text"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in your java file do this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
TextView toolbarText = (TextView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbarText);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)toolbar.findViewById(R.id.imageToolBar);
//Do your stuff here like set image on imageView
```

Happy Coding..:)

Comment: inflate menu in which search icon should be there. in your toolbar add a searchview Component set its visibility to be hidden `<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id  ="@+id/searchView"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:searchIcon="@null"
                >`
, and then toggle between views

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly like WhatsApp then you need to make a custom drawable having both back button and Profile image in same drawable image using Bitmap and Canvas. Then set this drawable image as HomeAsUpIndicator

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.custom_back);
```

Comment: Yes. Basically you can make a static function which takes Context and profile image in Bitmap and returns the Drawable Image. So when you open your ChatScreen you can call this function with Image of person with whom chat has been initiated .